# How to prevent Overlay from covering AppBar?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-appbar, flutter-positioned

I have a custom widget positioned in a `Stack`. This custom widget creates an `OverlayEntry` linked to its position and inserts it into an `Overlay`.

The problem is that this overlay floats above the AppBar and the FloatingActionButton.

How to put `OverlayEntry` below the `AppBar` but above the contents of my `Stack`?

**UPD**: By "below" I mean that the `AppBar` should float over the `OverlayEntry` (or cover it, as if it has a bigger z-index).

This is what I have:

[image]

This is what I'd like to have:

[image]

Sample code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: OverlayDemo(),
    ),
  );
}

class OverlayDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('AppBar + Overlay'),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            top: 10,
            left: 100,
            child: WidgetWithOverlay()
          )
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}


class WidgetWithOverlay extends StatefulWidget {
  const WidgetWithOverlay({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _WidgetWithOverlayState createState() => _WidgetWithOverlayState();
}

class _WidgetWithOverlayState extends State<WidgetWithOverlay> {
  OverlayEntry? overlayEntry;

  void showOverlay() {
    print(overlayEntry);
    if (overlayEntry == null) {
      overlayEntry = OverlayEntry(
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return Positioned(
                top: 0.0,
                left: 0.0,
                child: IgnorePointer(
                  child: Container(
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                )
            );
          }
      );
      Overlay.of(context)!.insert(overlayEntry!);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
      onPressed: showOverlay,
      child: Text('Show Overlay')
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Wrap the scaffold with SafeArea()

Comment: @Why_So_Ezz I don't think it's going to help.

Comment: @Warwick did u found any solution i m also facing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

put Stack above the scaffold then first child of stack will be WidgetWithOverlay() second child scaffold.

Comment: please share some example code.

Answer (score 0):

by default the `Appbar` height is `kToolbarHeight`,so you can create your overlay like so:

```
  overlayEntry = OverlayEntry(
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Positioned(
            top: kToolbarHeight,
            left: 0.0,
            child: IgnorePointer(
              child: Container(
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
            )
        );
      }
  );
```

Comment: I think I didn't use the correct wording for what I'm looking for. What I mean is that the `OverlayEntry` should be _covered_ by `AppBar`. So it should have lower z-index if that's a suitable term.